# Update a line in a config, or add it if it doesn't exist

Tags: bash, apache, shell

I need to write a bash script to check over an apache2 config file, and update 2 settings if they exist, or add them in if they don't.

My bash skills are not brilliant, but I know I need to use grep to find to try and find the line in the file.  But I'm not sure how to find the line in the file, then update just the value part if the key exists.

the settings I need to update are

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

inside the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf` file.

is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had half an hour spare just now so thought I would give this a go.  I've tried to annotate the code throughout, but if you're unsure you might want to ask questions on specific bits.

This relies on sed's `-i` option, which I know does not ship with all versions of Sed, so this is a limitation, but it should get you going. I've written it on MacOS Mojave.

It handles incorrect entries, skips correct ones and allows you to update the filename and configuration options easily using variables.  It'll also output status on what it's upto.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# The file on which to perform a "find and replace"
FILE="/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf"

# Use grep to find lines containing each required line
CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS=$(grep ^ServerTokens "$FILE")
CHECK_SERVER_SIGNATURE=$(grep ^ServerSignature "$FILE")

# Specify what the good config looks like.  This will be used in the find and replace.
TOKENCONFIG="ServerTokens Prod"
SIGNATURECONFIG="ServerSignature Off"

# If the grep above found no results, add the config in.
if [ -z "$CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS" ]; then
  echo "$TOKENCONFIG" >> "$FILE"
# If the grep above contains a result but it does not match desired config, replace it with desired config.
elif [ "$CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS" != "$TOKENCONFIG" ]; then
  # Use sed to "find and replace" wrong config, with desired config
  sed -i 's/'"$CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS"'/'"$TOKENCONFIG"'/g' "$FILE"
fi

# If the grep above found no results, add the config in
if [ -z "$CHECK_SERVER_SIGNATURE" ]; then
  echo "$SIGNATURECONFIG" >> "$FILE"
# If the grep above contains a result but it does not match desired config, replace it with desired config.
elif [ "$CHECK_SERVER_SIGNATURE" != "$SIGNATURECONFIG" ]; then
  # Use sed to "find and replace" wrong config, with desired config
  sed -i 's/'"$CHECK_SERVER_SIGNATURE"'/'"$SIGNATURECONFIG"'/g' "$FILE"
fi

service apache2 restart
```

Comment: The stock sed on macOS requires `-i` to come with a value, like `-i ''`, as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks so much for this.  I can see what you're doing here and makes good sense.  However when I run the script, I get a `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated 's' command` error, and `sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated 's' command` I'm guessing one for each block.

Comment: OK I think I figured this out.  I had to change the original grep commands to check from the start of the line because I was getting many returned lines in the file where they had been commented out.  So `CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS=$(grep ServerTokens "$FILE")` changed to `CHECK_SERVER_TOKENS=$(grep ^ServerTokens "$FILE")` which seemed to do the trick thanks.

Comment: I also don't need the comments and echos to screen since this command will run in the background.  I edited your answer a bit and marked it as correct.  Thanks for your help.